# Machine learning of word structure

Tags: language-agnostic, machine-learning, linguistics

I am working on a system that can create made up fanatsy words based on a variety of user input, such as syllable templates or a modified Backus Naur Form. One new mode, though, is planned to be *machine learning*. Here, the user does not explicitly define any rules, but paste some text and the system learns the structure of the given words and creates similar words.

My current naïve approach would be to create a table of letter neighborhood probabilities (including a special *end-of-word* "letter") and filling it by scanning the input by letter pairs (using whitespace and punctuation as word boundaries). Creating a word would mean to look up the probabilities for every letter to follow the current letter and randomly choose one according to the probabilities, append, and reiterate until *end-of-word* is encountered.

But I am looking for more sophisticated approaches that (probably?) provide better results. I do not know much about machine learning, so pointers to topics, techniques or algorithms are appreciated.

Comment: A small point : in languages, may it be if you generate sequence of words(another problem) or sequence of letters (what you ask for), it is often much better to generate a new word/letter taking into account the last **two** words/letters (rather than just one). It still involves the same algorithms. Additional words/letters don't yield significantly better results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that for *independent words* (an especially names), a simple Markov chain system (which you seem to describe when talking about using letter pairs) can perform really well. Feed it a lexicon and throw it a seed to generate a new name based on what it learned. You may want to tweak the prefix length of the Markov chain to get nicely sounding results (as pointed out in a comment to your question, 2 letters are much better than one).

I once tried it with elvish and orcish names dictionaries and got very satisfying results.